# Reading small amplitude audio with librosa

Tags: python, wav, librosa, amplitude

I am trying to load a `.wav` file in Python using librosa library. Let's assume my code is as simple as:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

pcm_data, spl_rate = librosa.core.load(resource_file, sr=None)
```

In general it does work, however I am experiencing strange quantization problems when reading audio files with amplitude of less than 1e-5. I need some really low amplitude noise samples for my project (VERY little ambient noise, yet not complete silence).

For instance, when I generate white noise of amplitude `0.00001` in Audacity, its waveform is visible in Audacity preview when fully magnified. It is also visible after exporting the waveform as 32bit float and re-importing it to empty Audacity project. However, when I read that file using code presented above, `np.max(np.abs(pcm_data))` is `0.0`. Did I just reach limits of Python in this matter? How do I read my data (without pre-scaling and rescaling in runtime)?

Comment: Are you sure the WAV file contains floating-point values, not integers?

Comment: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html says: "`audioread` may truncate the precision of the audio data to 16 bits." You should check the values you get, when you generate noise with amplitude `10` or something like that.

Comment: Bingo. I have to use pysoundfile explicitly, as it used to throw errors at some audacity formats. Librosa just falls back to audioread which is less precise. Thank you.

Comment: Great that you found the problem. @mkrieger1 you might want to add your comment as answer